# Internet issue in Android SDK 5.0 API 21Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to test my android app on emulator.I am using VPN and VPN proxy settings to connect to internet on my machine.So in previous version of Android emulator,I was setting  VPN proxy on emulator to get internet connection on emulator.But in the latest SDK (SDK 5.0),this is not working.Does anyone experience this issue.Please advise.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing such issue, and the emulator stops because isValidFd(fd) returns a number higher than 1024.

I've found a workaround that is working, at least in my case: launching the emulator from command line with `-no-audio` parameter added.

Comment: To bad, didn't work for me. I still can't connect to internet in my Android 5.0 (API 21) emulator, while I have no problem connecting to internet using other Android versions. Any other suggestions?

Comment: do you have any error message related to your issue ? How are you setting up the proxy ? `-no-audio -http-proxy proxy:port` is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, i had to turn 'WLAN/WI-FI off' on an emulator.